# Is it possible to turn off "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - XXX" messages in Firebug?

Tags: firefox, firebug

I do a lot of development on a local machine using a copy of the production database, which means that most of the image files referenced in the database are missing locally. Because of this, recent versions of Firebug flood the JavaScript console with `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - XXX"` messages every time I refresh a page, making it hard to see the actual information I need.

I've searched the Firebug site and Google Group with no luck. Is there a way to disable these 404 notifications and still see the pertinent debugging info?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on the small arrow at the right of the Console tab, and uncheck "Display network errors".

Comment: Do you know, I just never thought to look there! I even looked at the same little arrow on the 'Net' tab, with no luck... anyway thanks!

Comment: I have "Show network errors" checked. But, the console does not show any 404 errors. Any idea ?

Comment: If you've got show network errors and you're not receiving any 404 errors, flip over to the network panel and make sure it's enabled.